# SLicing a 3-d plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose in MATLAB I have obtained a 3-D plot, like `surf(peaks(20))` how do I get a slice along the plane `X=0`, and the corresponding 2-D plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a [contour](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html) plot:

```
data = peaks(50);

figure;
surf(data);

figure;
[C,h] = contour(data, [0 0]);
clabel(C,h);
```